# how can I upload and post image like facebook without page reload or refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

html code here

```
<form id="upload_img_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="add_picture" type="file" name="post_img" >
     <span  id="postbutton" >Post</span>
</form>
```

//I don't want to use the action at the form above, because the page would reload or refresh

I have done some of the research and knew the  dataform in ajax or jquery may work for this problem. But I don't know how to retrieve the data once I use jquery method

javascript codes here

```
$('#postbutton').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('#upload_img_form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: completeHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Basically, I don't know how to process the data in `'upload.php'`, and I have tried `$_POST['formData']` and I need to get the parameter for `move_uploaded_files($_FILES['file']['name'],$path)` in order to save the file to a specific path

Comment: try this move_uploaded_files($_FILES['post_img']['name'],$path)

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery should give you direction